# Appendices titles have different language

Tags: languages, appendix

I have the following problem. I have already inserted 2 appendices which show up as with a greek title - as intented (Παράρτημα Ι, Παράρτημα ΙΙ), but when I insert a third one I the output is "Appendix III" instead of "Παράρτημα ΙΙΙ".
The code I am using is the following

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\thepage}


\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}

\begin{document}

\input{chapters/titlepage}

\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Ευχαριστίες}
Θέλω να ευχαριστήσω..

\cleardoublepage 

\chapter*{Περίληψη}
Στην παρούσα εργασία θα γίνει μελέτη των μελανών οπών {\en Kerr}. Αναλυτικότερα, θα μελετηθούν περιστρεφόμενες και χωρίς φορτίο μελανές οπές με αξονική συμμετρία ως προς τον άξονα περιστροφής τους. Αρχικά θα γίνει εισαγωγή της μετρικής {\en Kerr} η οποία περιγράφει τη γεωμετρία του κενού χωροχρόνου γύρω από μελανές οπές {\en Kerr} και θα υπολογισθούν οι συνιστώσες της αποδεικνύοντας πως αποτελεί λύση των πεδιακών εξισώσεων του {\en Einstein}. Στη συνέχεια θα γίνει μελέτη των ιδιοτήτων του ορίζοντα μιας μελανής οπής {\en Kerr} και τέλος θα εξετασθεί η ύπαρξη κλειστών γεωδαισιακών που σχετίζονται με τις μελανές οπές αυτές.

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Εισαγωγή - Οι πεδιακές εξισώσεις του {\en Einstein}}
\input{chapters/introduction}

\chapter{Ο χωρόχρονος {\en Kerr} και η γεωμετρία του}
\input{chapters/chapter02}

\chapter{Chapter Three Title}
\input{chapters/chapter03}


\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{chapters/conclusion}

\appendix

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\chapter{Ιδιομορφίες ({\en Singularities})}
\input{chapters/appendix}

\chapter{Συστήματα συντεταγμένων}
\input{chapters/appendix2}

\chapter{Διανυσματικά πεδία {\en Killing}}
\input{chapters/appendix3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you have some `\en` command not in braces in `appendix2.tex`. It would be much better to define `\DeclareRobustCommand{\texten}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}` and use `\texten{Kerr}` and not abusing `\selectlanguage{english}`.

Comment: The problem is not in the appendix tex file. There is something going on with the third appendix because when I compile it the title "Appendix III" should be in Greek (Παράρτημα ΙΙΙ) like the previous appendixes as well as the chapters (their output is "Κεφάλαιο Χ") and contents (Περιεχόμενα) before that.

Comment: Try commenting out `\usepackage{alphabeta}` (that you shouldn't need) and see whether you get an error. If you do, then you'll know that there is a `\selectlanguage{english}` (likely due to `\en`) command in some improper place.

Comment: Well eventhough I did not really understand what I did wrong, I replaced the command declaration as well as the commands in text and now it works great! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Nevermind.. I was missing a } and that's what caused the problem. Anyways I guess having the command you proposed is better than "selectlanguage". Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The guess is that you're missing a `}` after `{\en`, so `\selectlanguage{english}` is not turned off.

I don't think you need `\usepackage{alphabeta}`, which is for inserting Greek letters in a non-Greek context.

More importantly, I suggest to avoid a command such as your `\en` and prefer something like

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\texten}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}
```

There are several reasons for this; the main one is that this is more efficient as it does not litter your auxiliary files with `\select@language` commands that slow down processing by executing useless instructions.

Two final suggestions: you don't need to load the `LGR` encoding and `\usepackage{hyperref}` should be the last in the packages.

Comment: I think that without the alphabeta pack i get a problem with greek in mathmode. As for the hyperref you mean I should put it last in the list of the packages?